# How can I find what process called ProcessRequest in an .ashx web handler file?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, ashx

I have a context.Request.QueryString item that is returning the wrong value in the ProcessRequest method of a .ashx handler.

The code is like so:

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

    Dim strOrderItems As String = Convert.ToString(context.Request.QueryString("OrderItems"))

End Sub
```

One of the values returned by "OrderItems" is wrong.  How can I find out what process has called this method to fix the incorrect data?

Answer (score 1):

It's called by asp.net framework code. Did you check the value of `context.Request.Url.ToString()`? It's more likely that the URL is not what you think it is.